# Cannot add Service-based database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am having trouble trying to add a Service-based Database to my C# Visual Studio 2013 project. The error message is shown below. It says I do not have SQL Server 2008 installed, but as shown, I do. The service is also running.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: The item I want to add]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, frustratingly you have to repair the installation of SQL Server 2008 and then do a complete uninstall of VS 2013 and install VS 2013 again, I found simply repairing the VS installation won't fix it - it needs to be a full uninstall followed by install.

Answer (score 0):

just go to server explorer and connect your database there,you will get a package to install,it is cylinder with a plug you need to click on it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).